# "OCI runtime create failed " issue running script on MacOS using Docker host

Tags: image, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run [`pishrink`](https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink) on MacOS using a Docker host, as explained [here](https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink/pull/27/commits/2c57342d9140bf90d721dbb3b76d304b97607a15). The `pishrink` script shrinks the size of an `.img` so it's quicker to burn onto an SD card.

I have Docker Desktop running, and I've add the repo to the top-level in my file system (`/pishrink`) and and running the following command:

```
docker-compose run pishrink /pishrink/pishrink.sh /pishrink/big-image.img /pishrink/small-image.img
```

When I do, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/pishrink/pishrink.sh\": permission denied": unknown
```

Can someone help me debug this issue? I'm relatively new to using Docker so I might be making some simple + fundamental mistakes.

Comment: Have you tried running that command with SU privileges? It seems unable to reach pishrink.sh

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with the following command, using `sudo` as suggested:

```
sudo docker-compose run pishrink /pishrink/pishrink.sh /pishrink/big-image.img /pishrink/small-image.img
```